# Name of i in loop - R

Tags: r, loops, names

I'm trying to extract the name of the `i` column used in a loop:

```
for (i in df){
  print(name(i))
}
```

Python code solution example:

```
for i in df:
  print(i)
```

PS: R gives me the column values If I use the same code than Python (but python gives just the name).

EDIT: It has to be **in** a loop. As I will do more elaborate things with this.

Comment: See "21.3.2 Looping patterns" at http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#for-loop-variations for a small example. Namely: `for (i in seq_along(df)) { nm <- names(df)[[i]] ; val <- df[[i]]; ... ; }`.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i in names(df)){
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: This may not be the most idiomatic way of doing things, but it works. No idea why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, you can use the `imap` function from the `purrr` package. When writing the code, `.x` is the object and  `.y` is the name.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30, c = 31:40)

library(purrr)

imap(df, ~paste0("The name is ", .y, " and the sum is ", sum(.x)))

# $a
# [1] "The name is a and the sum is 55"
# 
# $b
# [1] "The name is b and the sum is 255"
# 
# $c
# [1] "The name is c and the sum is 355"
```

This is just a more convenient way of writing the following Base R code, which gives the same output:

```
Map(function(x, y) paste0("The name is ", y, " and the sum is ", sum(x))
    , df, names(df))
```

Comment: Depending on what OP's trying to do he might also like `lmap`, which loops on single column data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
names(df)
```

to print all the column names in `df`. There's no need for a loop, unless you want to do something more elaborate with each column.

If you want the i'th column name:

```
names(df)[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
# Simulating your data
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,6)

df <- data.frame(a, b)

# Answer 1
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  print(names(df)[i]) # acessing the name of column
  print(df[,i]) # acessing column content
  print('----')
}
```

Or this alternative:

```
# Answer 2
columns <- names(df)

for(i in columns) {
  print(i) # acessing the name of column
  print(df[, i]) # acessing column content
  print('----')
}
```

Hope it helps!